# PHP cURL not return a response, POSTMAN returns response

Tags: php, curl, postman

I am running a cURL request that looks like this,

```
$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Authorization: Bearer " . $token
        )
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    die(var_dump($response));
```

Would there be any reason for the my cURL in PHP not returning a response?

Comment: Did you check the response codes?

Comment: You are not closing the curl connection.
Add this after you run curl_exec

`curl_close($curl);`

Comment: @SunnyPatel it returns 200.

Comment: @Azael it was being close I just didnt paste that link in my mistake.

Comment: Can you check errors with `var_dump(curl_error($curl));`?

Comment: If you are using Postman, you can just copy paste the PHP Curl code that Postman generates for you and test with that.

Comment: @Azeal done that response is empty

Comment: Update the curl is run on ajax GET command, where I get `failed to load response` if I open the request URL in a tab I get the response I am expecting.

Comment: Any chance you're doing a redirect or something before the ajax response is actually returned?