# cUrl not returning response - response is BOOL

Tags: php, api, curl

I am trying to verify my recapture with google, but I am getting a response of null

I copy and paste the information to Postman and sent the request and I received a positive response.

I copied the link in my browser as a GET request and I also got a response.

I am not sure what causing this, as all information is correct.

here is my code.

```
// set API URL
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
// Collection object
$data = [
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', //<--- my reCaptcha secret key
  'response' => $_POST['recaptcha']
];
// Initializes a new cURL session
$curl = curl_init($url);
// Set the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option to true
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the CURLOPT_POST option to true for POST request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Set the request data as JSON using json_encode function
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode($data));

// Execute cURL request with all previous settings
$response = curl_exec($curl);
// Close cURL session
curl_close($curl);
echo 'the response was ' . $response . PHP_EOL;
```

I saw this but didn't help me. [PHP cURL not return a response, POSTMAN returns response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670140/php-curl-not-return-a-response-postman-returns-response)

Comment: Per the [docs](https://www.php.net/curl_exec), `curl_exec` returns `false` on failure when `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is set, so that’s the answer to your titular question. But your real question is “it works here but not there” and the general answer is to inspect the returned response for errors which might help you debug further. If none, it is possible that the service is blocking your connections.

Comment: You're not handling errors

Comment: @chris Haas how can I know if the service is blocking my connection, I am currently trying it in my local host, my response is null, I don't see any blocked requests in console

Comment: If your code works when _installed on_ some hosts but not others, that's a potential sign. And if your code works _against_ some hosts but not others, that's another potential sign. "Network connection refused" or a similar error message is a common symptom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is an HTTPS url you may need to add:

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

It's a good idea to use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`.
I always use it. It is in my standard options.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

While Google does not return a 302 redirect HTTP status code, they do something funny with the initial request.  I made an HTML form and submitted it and a json response was returned but looking at the Browser's headers my initial request disappeared.

I do not think Google wants the post data as JSON.
In the API Request documentation is says METHOD:POST.  
It says noting about making the request with JSON.  
Google is expecting an array.
Try removing the `json_encode()`.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

If Google (unlikely) wants a JSON request, you need to add
`Content-Type: application/json` to the HTTP header.
By adding this header curl will put the "post data" in the body and will not use the
default POST header: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
$request = array();
$request = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
```

I do not understand why there was no response.  I would have at least expected:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "error-codes": [
    "missing-input-secret"
  ]
}
```

You may want to add this code after your `curl_exec($curl)`
This should give you all the details of you request and Google's response.

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$info = rawurldecode(var_export(curl_getinfo($curl),true));
echo "<pre>\n$info<br>\n</pre>";
```

If you want to see your outgoing request header (recommended) add this option and the header will be in the curl_getinfo:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
```

I'm a bit concerned about a NULL being returned.  Was the word NULL returned?  Or did you see nothing for `$response` in your string? 
curl does not return a NULL.  So maybe it was a false.  Meaning there is likely a typo. echo does not show boolean false if `$response` was `false` you would not see it. Maybe add a

```
if($response == false){echo "curl failed<br>";}
```

Even if it failed, all the above is still true.
I looked over your code and I see nothing that would cause curl to fail.  Even with the issues, there still should have been some sort of response. And there may have been an HTTP status code that would not show in your `$response`.  It would be in the `curl_getinfo`

Comment: I needed the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and remove the JSON. Thanks, Misunderstood

Answer (score -1):

Are you using your local machine in linux? If that so, it is probably because you don't have curl installed in your system. So do

```
sudo apt install php{version}-curl
```

Comment: I did not down vote you.  If curl were not installed there would be an Fatal Error.
`Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl()`  or the the HTTP response status code would be `500 Internal Server Error` if error reporting is turned off.